# Check if datetime is older than 5 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I am going to make a cron job in cPanel that runs every day, but not sure how the query should look like. I have a datetime column with this type of value: `2021-04-06 14:12:06`. How can select from table where datetime column is older than 5 days?

Comment: `datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date arithmetic.  Assuming you mean "day" without the current time value:

```
where datetime_col < curdate() - interval 5 day
```

If you want the reference to be the current *time* rather than the current date:

```
where datetime_col < now() - interval 5 day
```